# Matplotlib 3dplot, order not correct

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am having problems with matplotlibs 3dplot. If I plot two 3d objects, the one that is supposed to be in front is sometimes in the back. Take for example the following code

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

X = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
Y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
Z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(X+10,Y,Z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')



u=np.linspace(-2,2,100)
X = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(len(u)), u)
Y = 10 * np.outer(u, np.ones(len(u)))
Z = 10 * np.zeros((len(u), len(u)))
ax.plot_surface(Z,X,Y,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

pl.show()
```

It is supposed to plot a plane, with a sphere in from of it, but the sphere appears to be behind the plane.

[image]